# Reading csv file using pandas where columns are separated by varying amounts of whitespace and commas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read the csv file as a pandas dataframe. CSV file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3xc74f8v4winaj/aaaa.csv?dl=0

In particular,

1. I want to skip the first row
2. The column headers are in row 2. In this case, they are: 1, 1, 2 and TOT. I do not want to hardcode them though. It is ok if the only column that gets extracted is TOT
3. I do not want to use a non-pandas approach if possible.

Here is what I am doing:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3xc74f8v4winaj/aaaa.csv?dl=0', skiprows=1, skipinitialspace=True, sep=' ')
```

But this gives the error:

```
*** CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 4, saw 6
```

The output should look something like this:

```
                    1       1       2     TOT
0   DEPTH(m)        0.01    1.24    1.52    
1   BD  33kpa(t/m3) 1.6     1.6     1.6
2   SAND(%)         42.1    42.1    65.1    
3   SILT(%)         37.9    37.9    16.9    
4   CLAY(%)         20      20      18  
5   ROCK(%)         12      12      12  
6   WLS(kg/ha)      0       5       0.1    5.1
7   WLM(kg/ha)      0       5       0.1    5.1
8   WLSL(kg/ha)     0       4       0.1    4.1
9   WLSC(kg/ha)     0       2.1     0      2.1
10  WLMC(kg/ha)     0       2.1     0      2.1
11  WLSLC(kg/ha)    0       1.7     0      1.7
12  WLSLNC(kg/ha)   0       0.4     0      0.4
13  WBMC(kg/ha)     9       1102.1  250.9   1361.9
14  WHSC(kg/ha)     69      8432    1920    10420
15  WHPC(kg/ha)     146     18018   4102    22266
16  WOC(kg/ha)      224     27556   6272    34
17  WLSN(kg/ha)     0       0       0       0
18  WLMN(kg/ha)     0       0.2     0       0.2
19  WBMN(kg/ha)     0.9     110.2   25.1    136.2
20  WHSN(kg/ha)     7       843     192     1042
21  WHPN(kg/ha)     15      1802    410     2227
22  WON(kg/ha)      22      2755    627     3405
23  CFEM(kg/ha)     0
```

Comment: Row w index 1 seems to have more columns. Watch out if you use space as delimiter if you have non-quoted words with spaces.

Comment: Yeah, that row has `BD  33kpa(t/m3)`. that should be a single word, but the file has it with a space. I am ok if that row is skipped or ignored somehow

Comment: So are there quotes in the original file to let the parser distinguish BTW such spaces and delimiter spaces?

Comment: @ako, unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a regular expression to be used as your delimiter, in your case it will work with `[\s,]{2,20}`, i.e. 2 or more spaces or commas:

```
In [180]: pd.read_csv('aaaa.csv', 
                      skiprows = 1, 
                      sep='[\s,]{2,20}',
                      index_col=0)
Out[180]:
         Unnamed: 1       1       1.1        2      TOT
0
1          DEPTH(m)    0.01      1.24     1.52      NaN
2    BD 33kpa(t/m3)    1.60      1.60     1.60      NaN
3           SAND(%)   42.10     42.10    65.10      NaN
4           SILT(%)   37.90     37.90    16.90      NaN
5           CLAY(%)   20.00     20.00    18.00      NaN
6           ROCK(%)   12.00     12.00    12.00      NaN
7        WLS(kg/ha)    0.00      5.00     0.10      5.1
8        WLM(kg/ha)    0.00      5.00     0.10      5.1
9       WLSL(kg/ha)    0.00      4.00     0.10      4.1
10      WLSC(kg/ha)    0.00      2.10     0.00      2.1
11      WLMC(kg/ha)    0.00      2.10     0.00      2.1
12     WLSLC(kg/ha)    0.00      1.70     0.00      1.7
13    WLSLNC(kg/ha)    0.00      0.40     0.00      0.4
14      WBMC(kg/ha)    9.00   1102.10   250.90   1361.9
15      WHSC(kg/ha)   69.00   8432.00  1920.00  10420.0
16      WHPC(kg/ha)  146.00  18018.00  4102.00  22266.0
17       WOC(kg/ha)  224.00  27556.00  6272.00     34.0
18      WLSN(kg/ha)    0.00      0.00     0.00      0.0
19      WLMN(kg/ha)    0.00      0.20     0.00      0.2
20      WBMN(kg/ha)    0.90    110.20    25.10    136.2
21      WHSN(kg/ha)    7.00    843.00   192.00   1042.0
22      WHPN(kg/ha)   15.00   1802.00   410.00   2227.0
23       WON(kg/ha)   22.00   2755.00   627.00   3405.0
24      CFEM(kg/ha)    0.00       NaN      NaN      NaN
25,            None     NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN
26,            None     NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: the regex syntax `{a,b}` means "between a and b repeats of the preceding thing", i just chose 20 as an arbitrary maximum, but I chose 2 as the minimum to make sure that "BD 33kpa(t/m3)" doesn't get split

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the names of the columns.  Notice the trick I used to get two columns called 1 (one is an integer name and the other is text).

Given how badly the data is structured, this is not perfect (note row 2 where BD and 33kpa got split because of the space between them).

```
pd.read_csv('/Downloads/aaaa.csv', 
            skiprows=2, 
            skipinitialspace=True, 
            sep=' ', 
            names=['Index', 'Description',1,"1",2,'TOT'], 
            index_col=0)

         Description            1         1        2      TOT
Index                                                        
1,          DEPTH(m)         0.01      1.24     1.52      NaN
2,                BD  33kpa(t/m3)      1.60     1.60      1.6
3,           SAND(%)         42.1     42.10    65.10      NaN
4,           SILT(%)         37.9     37.90    16.90      NaN
5,           CLAY(%)         20.0     20.00    18.00      NaN
6,           ROCK(%)         12.0     12.00    12.00      NaN
7,        WLS(kg/ha)          0.0      5.00     0.10      5.1
8,        WLM(kg/ha)          0.0      5.00     0.10      5.1
9,       WLSL(kg/ha)          0.0      4.00     0.10      4.1
10,      WLSC(kg/ha)          0.0      2.10     0.00      2.1
11,      WLMC(kg/ha)          0.0      2.10     0.00      2.1
12,     WLSLC(kg/ha)          0.0      1.70     0.00      1.7
13,    WLSLNC(kg/ha)          0.0      0.40     0.00      0.4
14,      WBMC(kg/ha)          9.0   1102.10   250.90   1361.9
15,      WHSC(kg/ha)          69.   8432.00  1920.00  10420.0
16,      WHPC(kg/ha)         146.  18018.00  4102.00  22266.0
17,       WOC(kg/ha)         224.  27556.00  6272.00     34.0
18,      WLSN(kg/ha)          0.0      0.00     0.00      0.0
19,      WLMN(kg/ha)          0.0      0.20     0.00      0.2
20,      WBMN(kg/ha)          0.9    110.20    25.10    136.2
21,      WHSN(kg/ha)           7.    843.00   192.00   1042.0
22,      WHPN(kg/ha)          15.   1802.00   410.00   2227.0
23,       WON(kg/ha)          22.   2755.00   627.00   3405.0
24,      CFEM(kg/ha)           0.       NaN      NaN      NaN
25,              NaN          NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN
26,              NaN          NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Or you can reset the index.

```
>>> (pd.read_csv('/Downloads/aaaa.csv', 
                 skiprows=2, 
                 skipinitialspace=True, 
                 sep=' ', 
                 names=['Index', 'Description',1,"1",2,'TOT'], 
                 index_col=0)
     .reset_index(drop=True)
     .dropna(axis=0, how='all'))

          Description            1         1        2      TOT
    0        DEPTH(m)         0.01      1.24     1.52      NaN
    1              BD  33kpa(t/m3)      1.60     1.60      1.6
    2         SAND(%)         42.1     42.10    65.10      NaN
    3         SILT(%)         37.9     37.90    16.90      NaN
    4         CLAY(%)         20.0     20.00    18.00      NaN
    5         ROCK(%)         12.0     12.00    12.00      NaN
    6      WLS(kg/ha)          0.0      5.00     0.10      5.1
    7      WLM(kg/ha)          0.0      5.00     0.10      5.1
    8     WLSL(kg/ha)          0.0      4.00     0.10      4.1
    9     WLSC(kg/ha)          0.0      2.10     0.00      2.1
    10    WLMC(kg/ha)          0.0      2.10     0.00      2.1
    11   WLSLC(kg/ha)          0.0      1.70     0.00      1.7
    12  WLSLNC(kg/ha)          0.0      0.40     0.00      0.4
    13    WBMC(kg/ha)          9.0   1102.10   250.90   1361.9
    14    WHSC(kg/ha)          69.   8432.00  1920.00  10420.0
    15    WHPC(kg/ha)         146.  18018.00  4102.00  22266.0
    16     WOC(kg/ha)         224.  27556.00  6272.00     34.0
    17    WLSN(kg/ha)          0.0      0.00     0.00      0.0
    18    WLMN(kg/ha)          0.0      0.20     0.00      0.2
    19    WBMN(kg/ha)          0.9    110.20    25.10    136.2
    20    WHSN(kg/ha)           7.    843.00   192.00   1042.0
    21    WHPN(kg/ha)          15.   1802.00   410.00   2227.0
    22     WON(kg/ha)          22.   2755.00   627.00   3405.0
    23    CFEM(kg/ha)           0.       NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: thanks @Alexander, this is great. However, in my question, I do not want to hardcode the column names, because different files have different number of columns. the only column that will be present for sure is `TOT`

Comment: It is ok, if the only column you extract is `TOT`

Comment: @user308827 If you want to use Pandas for this, you at least need to know the number of columns to read.  This data format is very poor.